# $p'$-automorphisms of pro-$p$ groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, profinite-groups

Let $p$ be a prime and $G$ be a finitely generated pro-$p$ group admitting a continuous automorphism $\phi$ of finite order relatively prime to $p$. Let $\Phi(G)$ denote the Frattini subgroup of $G$. Since $\Phi(G)$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$, $\phi$ induces an automorphism $\overline{\phi}$ on the quotient $G/\Phi(G)$.

> Suppose that $\overline{\phi}$ is the identity on $G/\Phi(G)$. Is it true that $\phi$ is the identity automorphism of $G$?

When the group $G$ is finite, the answer to the question is Yes, cf. Theorem 1.4 in Chapter 5 of the book [Finite groups by Daniel Gorenstein](https://books.google.de/books?hl=en&lr=&id=hUsMFbMGZqoC&oi=fnd&pg=PR13&dq=finite%20groups,%20daniel%20gorenstein&ots=wopzl208JI&sig=rODtJR1GVvSM-gxj9vAbGwMlLyk&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=finite%20groups%2C%20daniel%20gorenstein&f=false).

Comment: Yes, this is an easy consequence of the finite case (since $G$ is f.g., if $\phi$ is not identity, there is a characteristic finite quotient on which $\phi$ is also not the identity). More precisely, the group of automorphisms of $G$ that induce the identity modulo $\Phi(G)$ is pro-$p$.

Comment: @YCor So let $H$ be a such finite quotient of $G$, is it clear that $\phi$ acts trivially on $H/\Phi(H)$?

Comment: Yes, since $H/\Phi(H)$ (the largest $p$-elementary abelian quotient of $H$) is a quotient of $G/\Phi(G)$ (the largest $p$-elementary abelian quotient of $G$) .